# Will "renamed" file's content be versioned

Tags: git

Silly question maybe, but i want to be sure:

Even though GIT does not store folder information and filenames as such AFAIK, it still recognizes a filerename has occured where it actually didn't  happen, i erased an old file, and put a new one in (with similar content).

Question is simple, will the data be correct in git, as in the new file is the one that's being used? (The cosmetic "renamed" I can live with)

```
$ git status
# On branch fooBar
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#       deleted:    src/main/resources/OLD.xls
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/main/resources/NEW.xls

$ git add .

$ git status
# On branch fooBar
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       renamed:    src/main/resources/OLD.xls -> src/main/resources/NEW.xls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data will be correct.

git automatically tries to detect renamed files based on the similarity between the old file (that was removed) and the new file (that was created). What you did is not different from renaming the old file to a new name and then changing its content. If the change in the content is small enough, it would be detected as a rename. If not, it would be detected as a removed file + a new file.

git Detecting the file as a rename is a good thing, since you can later track (with `git blame`) the origin of each line in the file (i.e. in which commit it was added and by who), even if the origin is from where the file had a different name.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, git will keep track of the contents of the NEW.xls file going forward. You can always view the full history of changes using the `--follow` option. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log for the usage of `--follow`, and http://thisbythem.com/blog/preserving-history-when-renaming-files-in-git/ for a fuller explanation.